# How to set up a task to update project automatically?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Is there a way to write a script or something so that my project in IntelliJ is updated automatically after a specified amount of time (say 1 hr)? 
If there is, then what other useful things can be done through such methods?

Comment: What do you mean, updated? Are you talking about svn, or git, or something?

Comment: Update as in "Update Project" (VCS->Update Project...). Mine's currently on svn.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. What would you do with merge conflicts if it were to happen an an inappropriate time -- like when you were in the middle of a debug session?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to have an `update` executed periodically. Doing background updates is problematic since merges have to be done and conflicts have to be resolved.

You can however set IDEA to check for incoming changes and "'Changed on sever' conflicts". Go to *Settings > [Project Settings] > Version Control > Background*. Turn on the "Refresh changes every x minutes" and/or "'Changed on sever' conflicts Check every x minutes". (If you want this as a default for future new projects, set it in *File > Other Settings > Default Settings*.)

On the "Changes" tool window is an incoming tab (for some Version Control Systems). This tab's refreshing is what the first option sets. Additionally, an incoming changes icon [image] will appear on the far right of the status bar just to the left of the memory usage graph.

I believe any 'Changed on sever' conflicts are reported via a notification bubble as set in the "Notifications" settings pane.  Also, if you start to edit a file that has a newer version on the VCS server, IDEA will immediately warn you.